# an assignment has two Equal sign

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, assignment-operator

following code we always use and is alright,

```
while(int c=getchar() != 'q');
```

but if change the ints to pointers like below, compile will rise an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int* c=0;
  if(int* a =c !=0)
    printf("ok");
}

error: cannot convert `bool' to `int*' in assignment
```

what had happened here? seems the priority was changed. can anyone give me a hint. and if I change it to this, it will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int* c=0;
  int* a;
  if((a =c) !=0)
    printf("ok");
}
```

Comment: `while ( int c = getchar() != 'q' )`: *we always use and is alright* might be an overstatement depending on what the expected semantics are, but that is not producing the semantics you seem to be expecting from the second example...

Comment: yes, I'm totally wrong on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, operator precedence hasn't changed between the two code snippets. The following:

```
while(int c=getchar() != 'q')
```

is equivalent to:

```
while(int c = (getchar() != 'q'))
```

Here, `getchar()` is called, its return value is compared to `'q'`, and **the result of the  comparison** is stored in the `int` variable `c`.

In other words, `c` doesn't contain the character that's just been read; it contains a boolean indicator saying whether the most recent character was `'q'`.

Since `c` is never looked at, the code works. However, it is probably not what was intended.

Answer (score 6):

Because of precedence,  `while(int c=getchar() != 'q');` is wrong. It will always store the result of comparing the value returned by `getchar()` and `q`. So **`c` will always be `1` or `0`**.

You likely want:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != 'q');
      ^             ^
```

Or maybe

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'q');
```

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed seeing precedence in action.

`!=` has higher precedence than `=`.  So

```
int* a =c !=0
```

parses as

```
int* a = (c !=0)
```

which is an assignment of a `bool` to an `int*`